# C Search duplicates in 2D array and working with indexes

Tags: arrays, c

I am a kind of newbie in C so pardon me if i got something very wrong.

There is a problem i cant solve myself.

```
15 5
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
```

This is one of the input files i got called "ex1.be"
The first 2 number represents the 2D array's column and row, the rest is the data inside it.

My tasks first part is to "manage a robot" which gathers the numbers "1". If there is no "1" in the first row, the robot starts at the top left corner "[0][0]" otherwise at the position of the "1" which is [0][2] in this case. The robot can move only one "index" after each row so if the robot starts at [0][2] then in the next row it can be [1][1], [1][3] or can stay at [1][2]. The robot have to gather as many "1" as it can, but here comes the final part of the task that i need to count how much "1" will the robot miss either way.
For example at the 7th row there is 2 number "1" and it can only collect one of them.

Where i stuck currently at, is that i cant combine the program parts. My guess is that i have to know how much "1"s are in each row, for that i have to make 3 else-if statement for each case (zero "1", one piece of "1" and more piece of "1"). And a "for" cycle to  get the indexes of the "1"s. This two, i cant combine.There is my program so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int rocket;  // the end return value
    int sum = 0;   // sum of each row
    int x;
    int i, j;
    int row, col;       //row, column
    FILE* ex1 = fopen("ex1.be", "r");
    fscanf(ex1, "%d %d", &row, &col);    //Row Column Initialization
    int matrix[row][col];   //Mátrix declaration

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)     //Matrix
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            fscanf(ex1, "%d", &matrix[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {  //mátrix draw
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (row = 0; row < i; row++) {
        sum = 0;
        for (col = 0; col < j; col++)
        {
            sum = sum + matrix[row][col];
        }
        if (sum < 1) {
            printf("zero rocket\n");
        }
        else if (sum == 1) {     //this part doesnt work as i would like it...
            if (matrix[i][j] == 1) {
                x = j + 1;
                printf("%d\n", x);
                x = 0;

            }
        }
        else if (sum > 1) {
            printf("more than one rocket\n");
        }
    }

    sleep(10000);
    return rocket;
}
```

There is many useless printf i know, those are for self-cheks. After this my guess is that i only need to do a few addition, subtraction and i could get the final number for the missing "1"s (rockets in my program because the task is covered in a fantasy scenario. Catching asteroids, and knowing how many rockets i need for the missed asteroids).

Comment: `i < row` or `row < i`. Pick one

Comment: Can you post a link to the original programming task?

Comment: Sadly its not english, its hungarian :(

Answer (score 1):

```
for (row = 0; row < i; row++) 
{
    matrix[i][j]
    ...
}
```

This is not a proper loop. First, you are loosing the value of `row` and `col`. `i` and `j` remain constant, you don't go over the matrix elements. You have already worked it out for printing the elements, you just need to repeat that loop.

`sum` value has to be initialized each time. I don't what you intend to do with `x`, but the code should be more like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    sum = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        sum = sum + matrix[i][j];
    if (sum == 0)
        printf("zero rocket\n");
    else if (sum == 1)
    {    
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if (matrix[i][j] == 1)
            {
                printf("%d\n", j + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (sum > 1) 
    {
        printf("more than one rocket\n");
    }
}
```